# Как найти координаты объекта на фото, если на фото только этот объект и вокруг белый фон?

Tags: python

Подскажите пожалуйста, как найти координаты объекта на фото? На фото только один этот объект, а всё остальное белый фон

Comment: если объект не точечный, то о каких именно координатах вы говорите?

Comment: @Zhihar О координатах по Х и У. Нужно нарисовать рамку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выделяете все элементы изображения, отличающиеся от "белого фона". С точки зрения программирования - получаете двумерный массив, имеющий нулевые значения для тех пикселей, цвет которых "белый" и единицы для тех, у которых цвет "не белый". Далее находите "центр массы" выделенного изображения или говоря на программистском языке - центроид фигуры, образованной единицами указанной матрицы. Координаты центроида и можно считать "координатами вашего объекта на фото".

Все подсказки теперь у вас есть - и ключевые слова для Гуугл-запроса, и способ переноса математического решения на вашу конкретную задачу. Надеюсь - далее справитесь самостоятельно. Останутся вопросы -  задавайте.

Comment: Я понял, что Вы очень умны. А готового решения из коробки нет?

Comment: Есть, но только для умных. У вас в тегах указан только Python. О какой коробке идет речь?

Comment: Большое спасибо)

Comment: А, на Питоне же всё самому делать нужно, точно, забыл

Comment: Нет, это значит, что вопрошающий ничего кроме Python использовать не хочет. Или не умеет. Кстати, "координаты объекта" и "рамочка вокруг объекта", которая появилась значительно позже - это как бы разные понятия.

Comment: А то, что то, что я написал реализуется легко и просто на "только Python". Впрочем, как и "рамочка". И не удаляйте свои комментарии после того, как на них ответили. Это считается неприличным.

Comment: Вы слишком быстро отвечаете) Спасибо